# difference between XMLHttpRequest and $ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have read about jQuery ajax method, jQuery wraps some XMLHttpRequest inside. 
I need(want) to redo next stuff to $ajax, but I worried about parameters. Is it possible send to $ajax url with parameters without param key, just in URL param ?

```
var element ;
   ...
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,... 
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    http_request.onreadystatechange = function() { alertContents(element); };
    url = unescape(url + parameters);
    http_request.open('GET', url, true);
    http_request.send(null);
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... do you want to remove the `parameters` var from the unescape function?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. I suggest you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and have a look at examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this same code for ajax consumes the time**

```
$.ajax({
     type: "get",
url: "geocode.php?address="+address,
    dataType: "xml",
    //async:true,
    success  : function(xmlData){
         alert(xmlData);     
    },
    error    : function(){
         alert("Could not retrieve XML file.");
    }

     });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use $.ajax you could write

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: parameters
    success: function(data) {
        alertContents(element);
    }
});
```

Comment: The only possible issue here is if the `parameters` start with a `?`, this may be a problem, though I've not tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much anything you can do using the `XMLHttpRequest` you can do with jQuery (jQuery uses  `XMLHttpRequest` for ajax).

```
$.ajax({
  url: url + parameters,
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

you could also set the parameters in the data option so that the type option will send it as POST or GET based on what you supply to it.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: parameters,
  type: "GET", // or POST, or any other valid type
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the answer is yes, you can.

The following are equivalent:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "some.php?name=John&location=Boston"
});
```

---

```
$.ajax({
  url: "some.php",
  data: "name=John&location=Boston"
});
```

---

```
$.ajax({
  url: "some.php",
  data: {
      name : "John",
      location : "Boston"
  }
});
```